# If ssl session is established does it mean specific version of tls is supported?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I am running openssl to check if web server supports tls 1.0. But looking at the response it seems it is not since SSL-Session ciper is 0000 but ssl session is established.
But when I am scanning my server through https://www.ssllabs.com/ it is saying that TLS version 1.0 is supported.
So not sure what exactly is happening.

Using apache for web server and already checked there and there tls v1.0 is disabled.

Also When running the same scan against another similar setup all things are working as expected and https://www.ssllabs.com/ also says TLS 1.0 is not supported.

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>***openssl s_client -connect test.server.cloud:443 -servername test.server.cloud -tls1***

```
CONNECTED(00000140)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.server.cloud
verify return:1
E81F0000:error:0A0C0103:SSL routines:tls_process_key_exchange:internal error:ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:2252:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.server.cloud
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Feb  2 15:55:04 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Feb 27 07:09:10 2023 GMT
 1 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", CN = Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: May  3 07:00:00 2011 GMT; NotAfter: May  3 07:00:00 2031 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
*********************************
*********************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = *.server.cloud
issuer=C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3350 bytes and written 148 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 42430000BACE6D963C2154287E5949A5BCEA93B1E8895F656FD8AF82FAF41625
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1663242412
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin>

Comment: "New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)" means no TLS session was established, for the reason outlined before it: "Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate".  The below SSL-Session block is almost empty showing no TLS is taking place. Also as this stage and form your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  ok thanks. do you know why it shows certificate and session-id in response

Comment: SessionId is just a random number generated by server and sent with its first message (ServerHello). The certificate is shown before the error, which one is directly related to the certificate in fact.